# pdf report generate in python 2.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I wrote a [code](https://dpaste.de/RosE) for pdf file report generate, but facing an error.

> TypeError at /billing/invioce_report/
>
> **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

How to write response and make downloadable file?

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='"application/pdf"')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.pdf"'
         **writer = pyPdf.PdfFileWriter(response)**
        writer.writerow(
            ['Creation Date', 'Bill Number', 'Name', 'Product/Service Name', "Ref No", "Cost", "discounted Price","Net Amount",
            "Costomer Name", "Commission Staff", "Commission Amount", "Patyment Type"])
```

Comment: please edit the question, do you have a piece of code we can help you with?

Comment: @hansTheFranz check edit code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a PDF it is better to use a wkhtmltopdf(PDF kit) for that you need to convert your contents to html